# How can I find the maximum and minimum date in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I need to find the maximum and minimum date from a given array using PHP.

I have $date_arr which contains following values,

```
  $date_arr = array('0'=>'20-05-2015','1'=>'02-01-2015','2'=>'30-03-2015');
```

Here, I need to get the larger date as '20-05-2015' and the minimum date as '02-01-2015'.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<?php

$date_arr=array(0=>'20-05-2015',1=>'02-01-2015',2=>'30-03-2015');

usort($date_arr, function($a, $b) {
    $dateTimestamp1 = strtotime($a);
    $dateTimestamp2 = strtotime($b);

    return $dateTimestamp1 < $dateTimestamp2 ? -1: 1;
});

echo 'Min: ' . $date_arr[0];
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Max: ' . $date_arr[count($date_arr) - 1];


?>
```

Comment: why would you sort the dates increasing the complexity to at least nlog(n)? You can just iterate through all the dates

Comment: I do not know why, but it does not work... $date_arr[0] return max one, $date_arr[count($date_arr) - 1] return medium one :( how about the min one?

Comment: @Eternal yeah, good catch, but actually, this approach *keeps* the given date format. Otherwise, it's faster.

Answer (score 19):

`max()` and `min()` works fine with your array:

```
echo "Latest Date: ". max($dates)."\n";
echo "Earliest Date: ". min($dates)."\n";
```

Comment: Best approach! Thx ! Works even with '2018-12-06T10:00:00.000' format.

Comment: This answer is misinforming researchers and will not work with the OP's `dd-mm-yyyy` formatted strings.  This answer is incorrect.  In other cases with a date format starting with the year and progressing to smaller units, this can work just fine.

Comment: Note that, whether `null` or any other empty char is present, that would be the minimum.

Comment: @mickmackusa I don't really think the format is an issue, strtotime() can be used to convert the timestamp value.

Comment: ... but this answer is not calling `strtotime()` to convert the strings into a comparable format and is therefore misinforming researchers. @Reln  [Watch Azima's answer fail.](https://3v4l.org/cj3eq)

Comment: plain wrong. 

`echo max(["20-01-2015","15-05-2016","10-04-2017"]);`
gives
`20-01-2015`

string to integer conversion only extracts at the first number in the text, in this case the day (20, 15, 10) and "sorts" by those.

Answer (score 4):

please Try this

```
$date_arr = array('0' => '20-05-2015', '1' => '02-01-2015', '2' => '30-03-2015');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($date_arr); $i++)
{
    if ($i == 0)
    {
        $max_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date_arr[$i]));
        $min_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date_arr[$i]));
    }
    else if ($i != 0)
    {
        $new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date_arr[$i]));
        if ($new_date > $max_date)
        {
            $max_date = $new_date;
        }
        else if ($new_date < $min_date)
        {
            $min_date = $new_date;
        }
    }
}
echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($max_date));
echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($min_date));
```

Comment: I like it because it is deeper, not realy dependent on PHP functions! I need it in VB and sure enough I can use it with some easy conversion of functions. The solution is elegant, simple, clear and - as I stated - universal! Thnx

Comment: This answer is not elegant; it is verbose.  It is also unnecessarily adding a time component to the date strings.  It is performing a re-count on every iteration.  `strtotime()` would have been just fine without all of the extra `date()` calls in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thought it doesn't technically offer the lowest computational time complexity, `array_multisort()` is a sensible, readable, concise approach.  My snippet only calls `strtotime()` on each element once -- `usort()` cannot match this claim.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1hKGD))

```
$dates = ['20-05-2015', '02-01-2015', '30-03-2015', '10-01-1990'];
array_multisort(array_map('strtotime', $dates), $dates);

printf(
    "Latest Date: %s\nEarliest Date: %s",
    $dates[array_key_last($dates)],
    $dates[0]
);
```

Output:

```
Latest Date: 10-01-1990
Earliest Date: 20-05-2015
```

---

To arrive at the same result by calling `min()` and `max()`, just create a formatted copy of the dates in unix time.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Buogi))

```
$unix = array_map('strtotime', $dates);

printf(
    "Latest Date: %s\nEarliest Date: %s",
    date('d-m-Y', max($unix)),
    date('d-m-Y', min($unix))
);
```

---

If you want to use `usort()`, here is the most modern syntax with the spaceship operator and arrow function syntax. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/O2CiW))

```
usort($dates, fn($a, $b) => strtotime($a) <=> strtotime($b));

printf(
    "Latest Date: %s\nEarliest Date: %s",
    $dates[array_key_last($dates)],
    $dates[0]
);
```

---

This task can surely be accomplished tens of different ways.  I considered writing a `foreach()` loop with conditions to maintain temporary variables while making iterated comparisons, but I felt it was prohibitively convoluted for a rather simple task.

Answer (score -1):

```
$date_arr=array(0=>'2015-05-20',1=>'2015-02-21',2=>'2015-04-13',3=>'2020-04-30',4=>'2020-04-13');

$max_date=$date_arr[0];
for($i=0;$i<count($date_arr);$i++)
{
    echo $date_arr[$i]. ' ,';
    if( $max_date < $date_arr[$i+1])
    {
        $max_date=$date_arr[$i+1];
    }
}  
echo " Max= ". $max_date;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This is the correct answer to a different question.  Because the OP's question shows input dates in the format of `dd-mm-yyyy`, your solution is incorrect for this page.  It is also better practice to cache the count instead of counting on each iteration. Furthermore this is a code-only answer which means it is low-value on Stack Overflow.