# How to subtract array with dates to another array with date in php

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have two array with dates like start Date and end Date in want to get difference between both dates.

**Start Date**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016-05-25
    [1] => 2016-05-25
    [2] => 2016-05-25
    [3] => 2016-05-25
    [4] => 2016-05-25
    [5] => 2016-05-25
)
```

**End Date**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016-05-28
    [1] => 2016-05-28
    [2] => 2016-05-28
    [3] => 2016-05-28
    [4] => 2016-05-28
    [5] => 2016-05-28
)
```

**Want Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 3
)
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: i want to subtract like **end date** - **start date** = **diff.**

Comment: what is preventing you?

Comment: i dont know how to get diff

Comment: have you studied this http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your arrays are the same size, and the arrays names are `$startDates` and `$endDates`:

```
$differences = array();
for($i=0;$i<=count($startDates)-1;$i++)
{
   // we divide by 86400 since 86400 seconds per day
   $differences[] = (strtotime($endDates[$i]) - strtotime($startDates[$i])) / 86400;
}
```

You could also use `DateTime` objects with the `diff` method to get the difference between them (probably better idea, avoids possible divide by zero issues).

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
$differences = array();
for($i=0;$i<=count($startDates)-1;$i++)
{
   $date1 = new DateTime($endDates[$i]);
   $date2 = new DateTime($startDates[$i]);
   $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
   $differences[] = $interval->format('%a');
}
```

**Edit: since you comment that it does not work:**

```
$startDates = [
    '2016-05-25',
    '2016-05-25',
    '2016-05-25',
    '2016-05-25',
    '2016-05-25'
];

$endDates = [
    '2016-05-28',
    '2016-05-28',
    '2016-05-28',
    '2016-05-28',
    '2016-05-28'
];

$differences = array();
for($i=0;$i<=count($startDates)-1;$i++)
{
   // we divide by 86400 since 86400 seconds per day
   $differences[] = (strtotime($endDates[$i]) - strtotime($startDates[$i])) / 86400;
}

var_dump($differences);
```

Result:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(3)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(3)
  [4]=>
  int(3)
}
```

DateTime Method:

```
$startDates = [
    '2016-05-25',
    '2016-05-25',
    '2016-05-25',
    '2016-05-25',
    '2016-05-25'
];

$endDates = [
    '2016-05-28',
    '2016-05-28',
    '2016-05-28',
    '2016-05-28',
    '2016-05-28'
];

$differences = array();
for($i=0;$i<=count($startDates)-1;$i++)
{
   $date1 = new DateTime($endDates[$i]);
   $date2 = new DateTime($startDates[$i]);
   $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
   $differences[] = $interval->format('%a');
}
```

Result:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(3)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(3)
  [4]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Comment: Just modified my answer to prove it is working, just whatever you're doing doesn't seem to be :p

Comment: i have one more question how to sort and find minimum date in array $endDates = [
    '2016-05-28',
    '2016-05-25',
    '2016-05-02',
    '2016-05-22',
    '2016-05-28'
];

Comment: i did it this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688597/how-can-i-find-the-maximum-and-minimum-date-in-an-array) is helped me